# XSLT identity transform with append and root element namespaces

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to create an XSLT library for the common task of passing through most of the content of XML data with small alterations.

The include file currently looks like this (pass-through.xslt):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- change default behaviour to copying all attributes and nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- copy element but add a child node -->
  <xsl:template name="append">
    <xsl:param name="element"/>
    <xsl:param name="appendage"/>
    <xsl:element name="{name($element)}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$element/namespace::*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$element/@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$element/node()"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$appendage"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could then create a stylesheet which included it and not have to worry repeating yourself over and over (calling stylesheet).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:ns="http://example/namespace"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:include href="pass-through.xslt"/>

  <!-- only worry about the transform you want -->
  <xsl:template match="element-to-be-modified">
  ...
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you only want to add an element to the document then call "append".

```
<xsl:stylesheet
```

This works *except* for namespaces on an element I'm appending to. If I have an XML file with a namespace on the root element it chokes saying there is no namespace binding for the prefix. If I add the namespace of the root element to the library then it's happy but that kind of defeats the purpose of the library if you've got to go modifying it for every use.

I'd be happy adding the xmlns:ns="uri" to the calling stylesheet but the scope of the namespace declaration seems to only extend to that stylesheet - *not* to the included one where the "append" template is.

I'd like to be able to transform

```
<ns:root xmlns:ns="http://example/namespace">
  <ns:child>old child</ns:child>
</ns:root>
```

To

```
<ns:root xmlns:ns="http://example/namespace">
  <ns:child>old child</ns:child>
  <ns:child>new child!</ns:child>
</ns:root>
```

Without having to include the identity transform boilerplate every time. I've tried an assortment of things, including adding a namespace="{namespace-uri()}" to the element in the "append" template but nothing seems to preserve the namespace prefix on the element appended to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, when you call your named template "append" you are already positioned on the element you are copying/modifying, then there really is no need to pass the current element as a parameter. You can just use **xsl:copy** here

```
 <xsl:template name="append">
    <xsl:param name="appendage"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$appendage"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

In your example, you would just call it like this

```
<xsl:template match="ns:root">
   <xsl:call-template name="append">
       <xsl:with-param name="appendage"><ns:child>new child!</ns:child></xsl:with-param>
   </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Using **xsl:copy** should copy your element and retain the namespace.

Comment: I did try using `<copy>` but the appendage kept being appended to the *end* of the output and breaking it. I finally figured out that this was because I was matching on the root of the document (`match='/'`) rather than the root document element (`match='ns:root'`).

The problem with matching the root document element without context is that it could theoretically match another element deeper in the source XML that has the same name. Matching on `match='/ns:root'` should fix that.

Should I post the final XSLT file or do we assume people can figure it out for themselves from the answers?

Comment: I would assume people can figure out the main issue. Incidentally, you could also do `<xsl:template match="\*">` to match the root element, then it would cope should the root element name ever change.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<xsl:element name="{name($element)}">
```

by

```
<xsl:element name="{name($element)}" namespace="{namespace-uri($element)}">
```

Comment: I did try that (see end of question), for some reason it didn't work for me in preserving the namespace prefix. When I tried it again after you suggested it - it did work. (Thanks for Saxon btw)

I really should have been using <copy> though, as suggested by @TimC below.